# Why is this query duplicating results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not very experienced when it comes to joining tables so this may be the result of the way I'm joining them. I don't quite understand why this query is duplicating results. For instance this should only return 3 results because I only have 3 rows for that specific job and revision, but its returning 6, the duplicates are exactly the same as the first 3.

```
          SELECT
               checklist_component_stock.id,
               checklist_component_stock.job_num,
               checklist_revision.user_id,
               checklist_component_stock.revision,
               checklist_category.name as category,
               checklist_revision.revision_num as revision_num,
               checklist_revision.category as rev_category,
               checklist_revision.per_workorder_number as per_wo_num,
               checklist_component_stock.wo_num_and_date,
               checklist_component_stock.posted_date,
               checklist_component_stock.comp_name_and_number,
               checklist_component_stock.finish_sizes,
               checklist_component_stock.material,
               checklist_component_stock.total_num_pieces,
               checklist_component_stock.workorder_num_one,
               checklist_component_stock.notes_one,
               checklist_component_stock.signoff_user_one,
               checklist_component_stock.workorder_num_two,
               checklist_component_stock.notes_two,
               checklist_component_stock.signoff_user_two,
               checklist_component_stock.workorder_num_three,
               checklist_component_stock.notes_three,
               checklist_component_stock.signoff_user_three
               FROM checklist_component_stock
               LEFT JOIN checklist_category ON checklist_component_stock.category
               LEFT JOIN checklist_revision ON checklist_component_stock.revision = checklist_revision.revision_num
               WHERE checklist_component_stock.job_num = 1000 AND revision = 1;
```

Tables structure:

**checklist_category**

[image: i]

**checklist_revision**

[image: i]

**checklist_component_stock**

[image: i]

Comment: You missed something? First LEFT JOIN should have more then one param. Re-view this one http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
LEFT JOIN checklist_category ON checklist_component_stock.category
```

was certainly supposed to be something like

```
LEFT JOIN checklist_category ON checklist_component_stock.category = checklist_category.category
```

Most other dbms would have reported a syntax error, but MySQL treats checklist_component_stock.category as a boolean. For MySQL a boolean is a number, which is 0 for FALSE and != 0 for TRUE. So every checklist_component_stock with category != 0 is being connected to all records in checklist_category.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that and your explanation makes sense but its still cloning the results and displaying 6 instead of 3.

Comment: I took off the join you mentioned above and I'm still getting duplicates so I'm thinking its the second join thats causing problems ?

Comment: There is revision, job_num and category in the tables. I don't know what exactly you are selecting, so you should know yourself wether one or more of these fields must be the same in a join. You will have to add these then to your ON clause(s).

Comment: Yep, it clued in after reviewing my query piece by piece. I don't have devs to bounce ideas or problems off of at work so any input on this website helps me re-think and re-analyse things. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

First check your query as join is missing in your first left join. Also If you just want to get unique rows from your query then use of distinct just after select...

Comment: If you share both result set i.e. your query result and what you want then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As well as fixing Thorsten Kettner's suggestion, my foreign keys for the revisions was off. I was referencing the revision in checklist_component_stock.revision to checklist_revision.revision_num when instead I should have referenced it to checklist_revision.id.